# Simplify multipolygon in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, polygon, vertices, simplify, multi-polygon

I am working on Google Earth Engine and trying to simplify a multipolygon by first reducing its vertices and then removing unnecessary polygons that have fewer than 5 vertices.

```
var gaul = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level1');
var multipolygonLayer = gaul.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Sindh'));

var filterPolygons = function(feature) {
  var geometry = feature.geometry();
  var numVertices = geometry.coordinates().flatten().size();
  return ee.Algorithms.If(numVertices.gte(5), feature, null);
  
};

var filteredMultipolygon = multipolygonLayer.map(filterPolygons).filter(ee.Filter.notNull());

Map.centerObject(multipolygonLayer);
Map.addLayer(multipolygonLayer, {color: 'blue'}, 'Original Multipolygon');
Map.addLayer(filteredMultipolygon, {color: 'red'}, 'Filtered Multipolygon');
```

I have copied this code and have no idea about the “notNull()” function as the error says that its expects an argument of type list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error for the notNull filter is because you didn't specify a list of properties to pass to the filter, in your case it would be the "numVertices" only.

However, your solution requiring `ee.Algorithms.If` [is not recommended](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid_eealgorithmsif).

Furthermore, your line for number of vertices is actually computing the number of coordinates (twice the number of vertices):

```
var numVertices = geometry.coordinates().flatten().size();
```

Also, note that the smallest number of vertices in a polygon is 5, so you want to use a filter that keeps polygons if they have (at least) *more* than 5 vertices.

How about something like this?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/21bec5de1ece40c3044221192fa7880c

```js
var gaul = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level1');
var multipolygonLayer = gaul.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Sindh'));
//print(multipolygonLayer.size()) // Only one feature

var geom = multipolygonLayer.geometry()
var coords = geom.coordinates()
//print(geom) // MultiPolygon, 36775 vertices
//print(coords) // 648 elements -- each a List of coordinates

function featureFromCoords(c){
  var nvertices = ee.List(ee.List(c).get(0)).size()
  return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon(c),{vertices:nvertices})
}

var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(coords
.map(featureFromCoords)
)
.filter(ee.Filter.gt("vertices",5))

print(fc) // 554 elements
Map.addLayer(fc)
```

This will get you 554 polygons out of the original 648.